# Error when Connection remote mysql database using jpa in Springboot RestFull Webservice

Tags: mysql, spring, rest, spring-boot

I have made a Rest full web service in SpringBoot with MySql database using JPA, My web service working fine on `localhost` with a windows machine. But when I use it on Linux, it deployed successfully and created tables automatically on remote database on Linux server. But after that when calling web service for a select or insert query it throws an exception.

My code for making the connection is

```
@Bean
public DataSource getDataSource() {
    BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://serverip:3306/MARK7");
    dataSource.setUsername("abcd123");
    dataSource.setPassword("abcd123");
    return dataSource;
}
```

Exception:

`org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:242) at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:225) at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:417) at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59) at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213) at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147) at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:131) at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy150.save(Unknown Source) at org.gradle.dao.LiveBankService.create(LiveBankService.java:16) at org.gradle.dao.LiveBankService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$d7f33af4.invoke() at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:720) at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281) at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:655) at org.gradle.dao.LiveBankService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$bcb4635e.create() at org.gradle.GreetingController.test(GreetingController.java:98) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:222) at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137) at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110) at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:814) at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:737) at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959) at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893) at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:969) at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:860) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622) at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:845) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:87) at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121) at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:120) at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:61) at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:95) at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:113) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106) at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141) at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528) at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1099) at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:670) at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520) at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:80) at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49) at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126) at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112) at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:91) at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2066) at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1863) at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1839) at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:910) at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:355) at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:325) at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:2149) at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:78) at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:68) at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4126) at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:503) at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:468) at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:213) at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:275) at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:151) at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1106) at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.access$2000(SessionImpl.java:176) at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.load(SessionImpl.java:2587) at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:996) at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsDetached(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:306) at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:186) at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:85) at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:876) at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:858) at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:863) at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.merge(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1196) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:344) at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy140.merge(Unknown Source) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:293) at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy140.merge(Unknown Source) at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:442) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:483) at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:468) at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:440) at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61) at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281) at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136) ... 80 more Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'MARK7.transactionsmain' doesn't exist at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:686) at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:663) at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:653) at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:115) at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2041) at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1827) at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:1930) at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96) at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96) at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:82) ... 134 more`

Comment: whole code for database connection is

Comment: The error message __Table 'MARK7.transactionsmain' doesn't exist__ is self explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

in your log I can see this exception:

```html
80 more Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'MARK7.transactionsmain' doesn't exist at
```

so, are you pointing to a correct schema? or you didn't create this table.